# How to reference the output of a rule in snakemake

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

I was wondering if it is possible to use the output of a rule directly as the input of the next rule, without having to specify the path again.

I thought maybe something like this would work, but it does not in my tests:

```sh
rule A:
    input:
         in_file = "path/to/in_file"

    output:
          out_file = "path/to/out_file"
    shell:
       "...."

rule B:
    input:
         in_file = A.output.out_file # reference the output of rule A doesnt work like this
         # in_file = "path/to/out_file" -> this works but is less elegant i think

    output:
          out_file = "path/to/out_file"
    shell:
       "...."
```

Any help or insights are appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: There is a single rule `A`, but there may be multiple rule instantiations that produce different outputs.

Comment: So what I intend to do does not work? If snakemake keeps track of the wildcards then each output should also be unique.

Comment: Yes, each output is unique. Which output are you trying to reference?

Comment: If you imaging the DAG of the workflow, simply the one above if that makes sense.
Rule A produces exatly one output file for each wildcard. And Rule B should use that outputfile as its input

Comment: First of all, in general case rule A can produce multiple files consumed by B. Next, you miss the causality: Snakemake needs to know the input of B to construct this DAG, so you cannot reference input as "something above in DAG".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
rule B:
    input:
         in_file = rules.A.output.out_file,
    ...
```

Although I prefer to hardcode the filenames since it makes the script more readable.